# How to reduce unused javascript (from pagespeed) in Vue app

Tags: vue.js, pagespeed

I have a website called [www.cygonia.com](http://www.cygonia.com) that I ran through pagespeed insight.
When doing so I got high scores for Accessibility, Best practices and SEO but very low for Performance (both on mobile and on computer)
I tried to solve this by looking at "Reduce unused javascript" and saw that I have a lot of potential savings in (unmapped) under js/chunck-vendors.a3761b47.js but I don't know where that unmapped is coming from. 
See image
[image]

How can I reduce this?
Where is this in my vue code.

Thanks

Here is a link to the analysis 
 https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-cygonia-com/tmcgrmdens?hl=en&form_factor=desktop